# Cypress could not verify that this server is running

Tags: docker, cypress

I'm getting the below error when run the cypress docker container ;

references used: https://github.com/bahmutov/demo-docker-cypress-included#run-tests

Commands used from the above link;

```
npm install
./cy-run.sh
```

---

```
Running Cypress e2e tests headlessly without copying files
Cypress could not verify that this server is running:

  > http://localhost:4110

We are verifying this server because it has been configured as your `baseUrl`.

Cypress automatically waits until your server is accessible before running tests.

We will try connecting to it 3 more times...
We will try connecting to it 2 more times...
We will try connecting to it 1 more time...

Cypress failed to verify that your server is running.

Please start this server and then run Cypress again.
```

Comment: It looks like the script just runs the container, but doesn't run the server as well. If you start the server, either on your local machine or in a separate container with its port correctly exposed, does Cypress connect successfully?